# Magento 2: So I have upgraded my magento from 2.3.6 to 2.4

Tags: composer, magento-upgrade, magento2.4.2

So, I am trying to upgrade my magento from 2.3.6 to 2.4.

I have updated my PHP from 7.3 to 7.4 for that.
I am able to run composer install, composer update and all other magento commands without any error.
I have checked my database as well.
Everything looks fine for me.
But when I go to the url
127.0.0.1:8888/xyz/
I get "The requested URL not found on this server."

No matter how many instances I have created from scratch. I still get the same error. If anyone can help me it will be really helpful.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your database **core_config_data** table change the both url

web/unsecure/base_url  ->  http://127.0.0.1:8888/xyz/pub

web/secure/base_url  ->   http://127.0.0.1:8888/xyz/pub

Run the following command :-

1. bin/magento se:up
2. bin/magento s:d:c
3. bin/magento s:s:d -f
4. chmod -R 777 var/ generated/

Comment: Thank you for the solution. It solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

#### Confirm Document Root (Nginx/Apache)

I'm assuming you have this covered, but maybe verify that the document root is pointed to the correct location. Best practice is to serve the site from the `pub` folder of Magento.

#### Verify .htaccess files present (Apache)

The first clue I see is that you're getting a non-Magento 404 page.

Depending on where your document root is set to serve the site from, there should be an `.htaccess` or `pub/.htaccess` file present. It redirects all requests to the `index.php` entry point of Magento and would give you a Magento 404 page when trying to hit the `/xyz` url when it doesn't match any Magento routes.

If using **Apache**, I would confirm that those files are present. They come bundled with Magento.

#### Ensure URL Rewrites are Enabled

Do you have "use url rewrites" enabled from the admin? If you can't get to the admin to check/enable it you could do it in the `core_config_data` table or via bin/magento:

`php bin/magento config:set web/seo/use_rewrites 1`

Comment: I checked my pub folder and I have .htaccess file inside my pub folder. But when I ran the command  "php bin/magento config:set web/seo/use_rewrites 1" it gave me error  "The value you set has already been locked. To change the value, use the --lock-env option." . Any suggestions?

Comment: It's hard to say without being able to troubleshoot it directly. It looks like from that error that you already have web/seo/use_rewrites locked in app/etc/env.php. You could confirm it's value there as being 1, but I'm not convinced that's your problem as it doesn't look like the request even hits Magento.